# Binary Indexed Tree(Fenwick Tree) - Range update and point Query

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees

With the help of [TopCoder Tutorial](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-indexed-trees/) and [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42811/what-are-the-main-ideas-used-in-a-fenwick-tree/42816#42816), I was able to understand the basic idea of how basic the cumulative frequency sum is stored in the left subtree of a BIT node.I was successfully able to understand the point update and range query for which BIT is famous for.

Then I came across [this post](https://kartikkukreja.wordpress.com/2013/12/02/range-updates-with-bit-fenwick-tree/) which explained the range update and point query.Applying the idea which I understood for the point update,I couldn't understand the range update.

Is the idea for range update/point query different from point update/range query? Please help with the intuition behind range update/point query.

Comment: Could you make your question more self-contained. In particular, I've no idea what idea you're talking about in your second paragraph.