# Documentation of "bin number" trees

Tags: data-structures, trees, binary-trees, balanced-search-trees

**TL;DR:** I implemented a special (?) binary tree and can't find any further details on the method I used on the internet. I would like to know if there are any  scientific papers discussing my implementation.

---

**Long version:**

I saw this very interesting binary tree using "bin numbers" in [RFC 7574](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7574#section-4.2). The leaf nodes contain data and consist of even numbers, and a single integer can be used to address ranges of leaves.

```
                               7
                              / \
                            /     \
                          /         \
                        /             \
                       3                11
                      / \              / \
                     /   \            /   \
                    /     \          /     \
                   1       5        9       13
                  / \     / \      / \      / \
                 0   2   4   6    8   10  12   14

                 C0  C1  C2  C3   C4  C5  C6   C7
```

Implementation details are not part of this RFC, so I did the implementation myself. I use a flat array so that every node is positioned at the index of their "bin number" for fast O(1) access:

```
Tree = [ Node0, Node1, Node2, ... ]
```

I created some methods to inspect a single node:

```
depth(index) = log2( ~index & (index + 1))        // depth from bottom
pos(index)   = (index >> (depth(index) + 1)) & 1  // left or right
```

And some helper methods to navigate the tree/array:

```
lChild(index) = (index & 1) ? index - 2 ** (depth(index) - 1) : -1
rChild(index) = (index & 1) ? index + 2 ** (depth(index) - 1) : -1
parent(index) = pos(index) ? index - 2 ** depth(index) : index + 2 ** depth(index)
```

** = exp operator

**I am asking myself if I'm reinventing the wheel here.** I would like to verify and optimize my implementation but could not find any more information about this tree or storage method.

Does anybody know how to call this thing?

Comment: At first glance this looks like the arry implementation of [complete binary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays) like usually done in case of the heap priority queue. But I might be overlooking some of your specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes, it is an implicit data structure, but it is not breadth-frist. The method of index-calculation is different (more like a horizontal traversal from left to right)

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Please have a look at Binary Indexed Trees, which are also known as Fenwick trees. I am not really familiar with those, but the pictures in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/10541/4287) look similar to yours. (Fenwick trees have a specific use in mind though).